# Cron job to remove empty folders with a Python virtual environment

Tags: django, python-3.x, cron

I have a script which when called from the command line to remove empty folders, works with no problem. When on the server (Ubuntu) I activate the virtual environment, and navigate to the project something like

```
cd djangoprojects/some_project
```

and then run

```
python core/remove_empty_folders.py media False
```

All works fine.

Then I wanted to implement the same script using cron. I have made the above script executable first.

This is what I think should work (have tried many variants!) (all on one line!)

```
/home/username/virtualenvs/some_project_env/bin/python 
/home/username/djangoprojects/some_project python core/remove_empty_folders.py media False
```

Ownership of the media folder is www-data

However, it's just not working, and I am not sure why? I can't get any feedback from cron as to what the problem may be so hoping someone can help on this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm if it works when you activate the virtualenv, perhaps doing that from the cronjob might resolve the issue? Maybe something like this:

```
*/10 * * * * source /home/username/virtualenvs/some_project_env/bin/activate && python /home/username/djangoprojects/some_project/core/remove_empty_folders.py media False
```

I do this regularly with cronjobs that activate a virtual environment and then run a Django management command. If you still experience any difficulties, converting your Python script into a Django management command might be another route to explore (that would also let you tap into sentry logging to see any issues that come through):

```
0 2 * * * source /home/projects/someproject/venv/bin/activate && /home/projects/someproject/appcode/manage.py refresh_data
```

**EDIT**
One further debug step: You can add some diagnostic print statements and then see the output of the management command by looking in /var/log/syslog or piping the output of the cron job. For example,

```
*/10 * * * * source /home/username/virtualenvs/some_project_env/bin/activate && python /home/username/djangoprojects/some_project/core/remove_empty_folders.py media False >> /var/log/mycronjob.txt
```

If you do that, just make sure your cron user has file permissions over /var/log or wherever you put the messages.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for getting back. I've tried the first option (no luck) and did think about running a management command, which I will try next and report back. Many thanks,

Comment: No worries, good luck with step 2. I also just edited to offer some suggestions for how you might get some more info out of cron

Comment: Hi Robert, I am using a management command, am not getting any errors when I log but the empty folders are still not being deleted on the server. Could the problem be the path to the media folder? In the rest of my code I am just using "media" and that works?

Comment: Hmm have you confirmed that it's running at all? (maybe some filepath or permission is off so the python code isn't actually running). Alternatively, it could be that the cron job is running at the document root now so relative filepaths won't work anymore. If neither of those is the issue, would it be possible to post the contents of remove_empty_folders.py? I know you mentioned that it works when you run it outside of the cron job, but there could possibly be relative filepath, permission, or import issues in the code itself.

Comment: Hi Robert, many thanks for getting back. I'm going to look at this further today if I can and will report back.

Comment: Hi Robert, it was a file path issue - many thanks for your help on this